# node js docker-compose volume empty

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I've written an app that download some images to a folder called `storage` in `src/storage` path. everything works great in development mode (without container) and in production mode (container) it works but the volume will be empty.

**docker-compose:**

```
version: "3.2"

services:
  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./storage-data:/src/storage
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file:
      - prod.env
    networks:
      - app_network

networks:
  app_network:
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

RUN npm install

COPY ./src .

CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

and this is my **download** function:

```
const { createWriteStream } = require("fs");
const { pipeline } = require("stream");
const { promisify } = require("util");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const download = async ({ url, path }) => {
  const streamPipeline = promisify(pipeline);
  const response = await fetch(url);

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`unexpected response ${response.statusText}`);
  }

  await streamPipeline(response.body, createWriteStream(path));
};

module.exports = download;
```

and finally the code:

```
    for (const [i, product] of products.entries()) {
      const { thumbnail, name } = product;
      const ext = thumbnail.slice(thumbnail.lastIndexOf("."));
      const filePath = `${path.join(__dirname, "../storage")}/${
        brand.text
      }-${slugify(name)}-thumbnail${ext}`;

      try {
        await download({
          url: thumbnail,
          path: filePath,
        });
        products[i].thumbnail = filePath.slice(filePath.indexOf("src"));

        logger.info(`"${name}" thumbnail saved to ${filePath}`);
      } catch (error) {
        logger.error(error);
      }
    }
```

as I said, it downloads files in container but volume folder is empty and there is no error.

if I check docker container with docker exec i can see downloaded files.

Comment: Which path can you see the downloaded files? Can you share the Dockerfile as well?

Comment: @ErangaHeshan Dockerfile added.  files are downloaded in the src/storage folder.

Comment: You're mounting the volume on `/src/storage`, but your application code is in `/usr/src/app/src`.

Comment: @ErangaHeshan ```WORKDIR /usr/src/app``` work dir is Dockerfile is this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update:

You need to mount the volume to the absolute path you see when you execute `pwd` from a terminal within the container in the images directory.

---

You need to change your docker-compose file's `volumes` like below:

```sh
volumes:
      - ./storage-data:/usr/src/app/src/storage
```

Comment: Still creates empty folder

Comment: Is it still showing you images in the container? You need to mount the volume to the absolute path you see when you execute `pwd` from a terminal within the container in the images directory.

Comment: Hey man, you helped me to solve my problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: Could you accept my answer by clicking the tick sign near my answer then :-)